# How to extract audio from a video file and make it as JavaSound AudioInputStream?

Tags: java, jmf, javasound

I know JMF needs to be used to deal with video, but the JMF api is very confusing and difficult to understand. I saw something like [this](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?forumID=28&threadID=5342704) but what I want to do is the opposite I think.

Comment: try using this it might help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6899492/audio-converting-with-xuggler/12175486#12175486

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved. Xuggler is needed for doing the above operation. JMF is useless except for playing videos.

Comment: please can you provide details, how you achieved it.