# convert mp3 to wav using xuggle getting exception

Tags: java, audio, ffmpeg, converters, xuggler

I am trying to convert mp3 to wav and the code is here:

```
String mp3 = "F:\\work\\pic2talk38512.mp3";
String wav = "F:\\work\\pic2talk38512.wav";
TranscodeAudioAndVideo.transcodeTest(mp3, wav);

public static void transcode(String sourceUrl, String destinationUrl) {
    IMediaReader reader = ToolFactory.makeReader(sourceUrl);
    reader.addListener(ToolFactory.makeWriter(destinationUrl, reader));

    while (reader.readPacket() == null)
            do {
            } while (false);
}
```

I got this exception:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: could not guess codec
at com.xuggle.xuggler.IContainerFormat.establishOutputCodecId(IContainerFormat.java:454)
at com.xuggle.xuggler.IContainerFormat.establishOutputCodecId(IContainerFormat.java:327)
at com.xuggle.xuggler.IContainerFormat.establishOutputCodecId(IContainerFormat.java:300)
at com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaWriter.addStreamFromContainer(MediaWriter.java:1134)
at com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaWriter.getStream(MediaWriter.java:1039)
at com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaWriter.encodeVideo(MediaWriter.java:742)
at com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaWriter.encodeVideo(MediaWriter.java:783)
at com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaWriter.onVideoPicture(MediaWriter.java:1434)
at com.xuggle.mediatool.AMediaToolMixin.onVideoPicture(AMediaToolMixin.java:166)
at com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaReader.dispatchVideoPicture(MediaReader.java:610)
at com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaReader.decodeVideo(MediaReader.java:519)
at com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaReader.readPacket(MediaReader.java:475)
at com.renren.intl.soundsns.pictalk.utils.TranscodeAudioAndVideo.transcodeTest(TranscodeAudioAndVideo.java:75)
at com.renren.intl.soundsns.pictalk.utils.TranscodeAudioAndVideoTest.convert(TranscodeAudioAndVideoTest.java:12)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

I know that xuggle can figure out the conversion by the extension.But why this time is failed?

thanks

edit:

previously I can convert mp3 which params(MPEG 22.1KHZ 32kbps) to wav, but If I use the mp3(MPEG 44.1KHZ 62kbps) I got this exception?

How this happened?

Answer (score 4):

In this ,basically xuggle is complaining about your codec.I think you need to try this code

```
String mp3 = "F:\\work\\pic2talk38512.mp3";

String wav = "F:\\work\\pic2talk38512.wav";    
IMediaReader mediaReader = ToolFactory.makeReader(mp3);
            IMediaWriter mediaWriter = ToolFactory.makeWriter(wav, mediaReader);
            mediaReader.addListener(mediaWriter);
            // IMediaViewer mediaViewer = ToolFactory.makeViewer(true);
            // mediaReader.addListener(mediaViewer);
            while (mediaReader.readPacket() == null);
```

I hope you are using `xuggle-xuggler-5.4.jar`

Comment: Yes I am using 5.4 and let my have a try

Comment: @Felix ok let me know what happen then?

Answer (score 1):

### Update:

```
import com.xuggle.mediatool.IMediaReader;
import com.xuggle.mediatool.IMediaViewer;
import com.xuggle.mediatool.IMediaWriter;
import com.xuggle.mediatool.ToolFactory;
public class TranscodingExample {
    private static final String inputFilename = "c:/myvideo.mp4";
    private static final String outputFilename = "c:/myvideo.flv";
    public static void main(String[] args) {// create a media reader
        IMediaReader mediaReader =
               ToolFactory.makeReader(inputFilename);
        // create a media writer
        IMediaWriter mediaWriter =
               ToolFactory.makeWriter(outputFilename, mediaReader);
        // add a writer to the reader, to create the output file
        mediaReader.addListener(mediaWriter);
        // create a media viewer with stats enabled
        IMediaViewer mediaViewer = ToolFactory.makeViewer(true);
        // add a viewer to the reader, to see the decoded media
        mediaReader.addListener(mediaViewer);
        // read and decode packets from the source file and
        // and dispatch decoded audio and video to the writer
        while (mediaReader.readPacket() == null) ;
    } 
}
```

This is the code taken from Java Code Geeks. Try changing the path to your mp3 files and see if that works for you

### Proof of code working

[image]

### Trnscoding mp3 @ 64kbps to wav

[image]

Comment: I have used Xuggler previously. Let me have a look. In the mean time, try changing the back slashes to forward slashes :)

Comment: this is not the slashers issue.OP is using slashes correctly.

Comment: previously I can convert mp3 which params(MPEG 22.1KHZ 32kbps) to wav using demo code, but If I use the mp3(MPEG 44.1KHZ 62kbps) I got this exception.

Comment: I can convert mp3 which is downloaded from google voice to wav, but I can not convert my mp3 to wav.How this happened...

Comment: @LittleChild dont be so excited.It can happen because of the variations of codec.do concentrate what @felix is saying `I can convert mp3 which params(MPEG 22.1KHZ 32kbps) to wav using demo code, but If I use the mp3(MPEG 44.1KHZ 62kbps) I got this exception.` You need to read this comment again

Comment: @LittleChild Can I send my mp3 to you by email? If you don`t want to public your email here, my email is guofuchunlh@gmail.com and would you send me an email and I send mp3 to you? thanks ): I think my mp3 file is wrong but I can play it...