# how can i extract audio from a video file through java program

Tags: java, audio, video, jmf

i want to extract audio from video file and save as a audio file of any audio format,is it possible through java program.can i use JMF for this purpose,if yes how?,how can i use JMF in my program code,is there any better way?please post a sample code

Comment: may be this will be helpful to you http://stackoverflow.com/q/2712855/839527

Comment: I would not use Java for that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See http://www.xuggle.com/.  It provides an API that can extra audio and video data from pretty much any file.  Lots of examples and demos are provided.

Comment: Art Clarke xuggle uses FFmpeg and has its license - GPL, meaning that if you are using it your app's license need to be also GPL(and open sourced)